# Best way to express serving in an office with many clients

Tags: grammar, expressions

How can I simplify this, to explain that i am working in an office with high volume of clients whom I serve i.e.

`I work in a/an ____ office`

`I work in an office with ____`

Something close to that...

Comment: What about *crowded*?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul in a crowded office. how do i attach the name client . `client crowded office`  !

Comment: Against the law, in most countries at the moment.

Comment: I work in a **busy** office, which *implies* a high volume of clients.

Comment: That sounds okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work in an office with a high client turnout.

Comment: I like this answer because it specifies that it is the clients that make the office busy

Answer (score 2):

The sentence

> I am working in an office with high volume of clients whom I serve

can be simplified to

> I work in a **busy** office.

This *implies* a high volume of clients.